# how to check if camera is focused on something before taking picture?

Tags: android, android-camera, autofocus

In my camera app I'm setting camera focus mode to FOCUS_MODE_AUTO and I also implemented focus by touch. When user presses capture button I need to check if camera is already focused on something (by touch) or not to call Camera.autoFocus() before taking picture. how can I do this?

```
if (/* how to check ??? */) {
    mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        mCamera().takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
        }
    });
}
else {
    mCamera().takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FOCUS_MODE_AUTO, you basically have to trigger AF before each picture; in that mode, the lens does not move unless you're actively running autofocus, and the AF system does no monitoring of focus quality outside of the autofocus() call.

If you use FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE, then the AF system will try to keep AF well-focused at all times. You can use the [AutoFocusMove](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.AutoFocusMoveCallback.html) callback to monitor when focus scans start and stop; unfortunately, it's not guaranteed that when a focus scan stops, that the scene is in focus.

The scan can also stop because the device gave up and can't focus for the current scene.  That could happen, for example, if the scene is too close to the camera to be focusable, or if there's not enough light.

The old camera API doesn't have anything better, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
       if(success) {
           mCamera().takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
       } else {
            //NOT YET FOCUSED
       }
    }
});
```

**Edit**

```
boolean isManualFocused = false;
mCameraPreview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        isManualFocused = true;
        return false;
    }
});
if (!isManualFocused) {
  mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
       mCamera().takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
     }
  });
}
else {
  mCamera().takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}
```

Edit2:

You can listen to events like NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED to detect the case (please refer this for all events: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html)

Sample code:

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

```
private void process(CaptureResult result) {
    switch (mState) {
        case STATE_PREVIEW: {
             int state = result.get(CaptureResult.NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not what I want. I want to call mCamera.autoFocus() if the user hasn't focused on something by touching camera preview.

Comment: Edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: but when camera is moved away, camera focus is lost, too. I want to detect if the camera still has focus on something user wanted or no. Maybe there isn't such capability

Comment: Edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: My minSdkVersion is 19 and I can't use Camera2 API. if there isn't any solution for Camera API I can accept your answer.